# Where in code should one keep data that doesn't change?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined models based on the tables in the database. Now there are some models whose data hardly changes. For example, the categories of the products that an e-comm site sells, the cities in which it ships the products etc. These don't change often and thus to avoid hitting the db, these are currently saved as static variables.

The question is where in code should these static variables be located. Currently, in ProductCategory class (which is also the model representation) a static List is defined which if empty calls the db and loads the Product Categories. Similarly, the City class has a similar static List and so on.

These static Lists are then used across the application. I was thinking of creating a class called StaticData and then keeping all the static Lists within this class. That is now instead of

```
ProductCategory.AllCategories.Find(p => p.Id = 2)
```

I shall have

```
StaticData.AllProductCategories.Find(p => p.Id = 2)
```

Which do you think is a better approach? I am also aiming for testability and decoupled code.

Also, is there a better way to achieve these? How do you do something similar in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's static enough to be compiled into your code, and *never* has to change in runtime, you could use a static class, see for instance the common pattern of [turning enums into classes](http://sarahtaraporewalla.com/design/coding-tip-42-turning-enums-into-classes/).

Something like that should probably work well in your scenario:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public static Vehicle Car = new Vehicle("Car");
    public static Vehicle MotorBike = new Vehicle("MotorBike");
    public static Vehicle PeopleMover = new Vehicle("PeopleMover");

    private Vehicle(string name)
    {
        this.name = name
    }
    private string name;
}
```

Using an enum or a class with static members like that one should help you get rid of those nasty magic numbers in your code as well, but seeing as the syntax isn't correct there (missing an `=`) I'll assume that that's just sample code and doesn't look like anything in your real code base.

If changes do sometimes occur, and you would want your list of categories in the database, they could be tightly cached (as in almost never expiring, but manually invalidated on an update). Depending on the size of the list of categories, I'd consider putting the entire collection in one big cache, and querying the cached object for individual categories, rather than keeping one separate cache entry for each.

Comment: Yes, it is sample code. A similar approach is followed currently. The question is that there are scenarios where apart from the individual static variables like Car, Motorbike, I also want a collection Vehicles, which is also what is used across the code. Now where should this collection reside. Within the Vehicle class or in a separate class?

Comment: @sassyboy: I ususally put it within the class, yes. I would have a static readonly array called `All` that you could iterate over, which you could also use for utility functions like `Get(int id) { return All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id); }` if you have an `Id` property, for instance... (The `Get` method, then, also being a member of `Vehicle`)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) instead of static variables.

I don't know any detail about your code, so if you are using a repository you could do something like that:

```
if [cache contains object or collection I need]
{
   return [object or collection from cache]
}
else
{
   [get object or collection from database]
   [save object or collection in cache]
   return [object or collection from database]
}
```

Then, if you change your cached entities you have to find a way to delete those cached entries to retrieve fresh data from the DB.

Comment: when you do get to the quality conscious phase you will see that there is an expensive QA process between code changes and deployment.  also, focus on scalability instead of performance.

Comment: The data never changes. Which is why static variables are preferred. I don't agree that Cache is a better option here instead of static variables. And which object would I save in Cache, the individual objects or the collection.

Comment: Both, it depends if your repository method returns an individual object or a collection. You said "hardly changes"... I don't believe that e-commerce categories will never change! :)

Comment: Well e-commerce was just an example. In my case, it is fine if the data refreshes when the app pool restarts. I don't want to hit the db more than once for this type of data. But thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

No easy answer. You have several options and you will have to consider which one is better for your app:

- **You might use some kind of cache.**

  Maybe too complicated if product categories do not change often. This is ideal when you have performance problems (thousands of categories that are read often) and Product Categories changes often. You can benefit from any open-source cache system but this solution might be more complicated.
- **You might hardcode them as an Enum.**

  Only good if you are 100% sure Product Categories never will change... ever!
- **You might have a a Lazy Singleton or Static class.** (My preferred)

  IMHO best practice might be have a Lazy Singleton or static ProductCategory class. Ideal if you have few data that doesn't change very often, for example potentially can change on a release. There are two approaches:

  **Load in Init**: Static variables should be keep in business logic layer as constants, in your case you can preload Product Categories on application start and keep them all time. In this approach you expend time in application load.

  **Load on first use**: The first time you try to access the categories check if they are loaded or not. If no, class load them. In this approach you expend time in the first moment you need to access Product Categories.

  In any of these two approaches, data will be lost after each application pool restart so if you release a new version you will refresh data. In case of "emergency" update of DB you can always later restart application pools.

Comment: Well, the question is should the static List be part of ProductCategory class (which is the model class and has members matching the table columns from db) or should the static List be part of a separate StaticData class, which has staticLists for ProductCategory, City etc.