# Saving List<T> to save adding items on every start

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I use a `List<string>` to which I add a few hundred thousand of random strings to be then used within my program.

I need this list quite at the beginning of the program and the random strings which it uses are saved in a textfile. At the moment the first thing the program does after loading, is adding all the items to the list. However, since the list is exactly the same every single time I wonder if there is a way to save it somehow internally so the list can just be directly used and does not need to be expanded on every single startup.

Comment: pls check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240330/where-in-code-should-one-keep-data-that-doesnt-change

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that but it somehow seems that in that approach I will also not really save the how loop of adding every single item on startup...

@Cuong Lee: There is really not much to show, I just declare a `List<string>` and then add items via `list.Add("RandomString1"); list.Add("Ran...`

Comment: You may hardcode it of course. But if you need *few hundred thousand of random strings*, you'd hardly be happy with that. It'll save you time to read from any source (txt, xml,...) instead.

Comment: Well, the point is the strings are set and saved and will not be edited at any point (not even in the future) so hardcoding wouldn't really be a problem. I simply thought because of performance reasons that saving a "ready to go list" is more efficient than declaring one on startup and adding all the items every single time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list needs to be persisted somewhere otherwise when the application shuts down you will loose all values. When the application shuts down, the memory that was used to store this list is returned back to the Operating System. So, no, there's no other way to have the list in memory when the application starts without reading it from somewhere - whether this would be a file, database or some other storage you need to load it from there or regenerate it from scratch.

If you do not care about the file format in which the list is stored you could use a [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) for faster serialization and deserialization compared to XML, JSON and other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really mean to keep the list in memory, rather within the .exe saved somehow, just as I add the textfile to the project, I wondered if its possible to save and reuse the list.

Comment: No, you cannot modify the executable at runtime. You just need to persist the list in some file so that it is available next time you start the application.

Comment: The way I see it is not really modifying the executable at runtime. I thought it might be possible to write a small script that delares the list and adds all the items, then somehow save the "list as it is (in memory?!)" to a file, then add the file to the project and reuse the data saved as a list, thus saving all the adding of the strings...

Comment: No, only the containing process has access to its memory. You cannot modify the contents of some memory location that was allocated to a given process from the outside - that would be a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I guess I keep it the way it is now then and add the items to the list every time on startup.

Comment: Couldnt he read it one time from the textfile and then store it as an object in the settings? Or are a few hundred thousand strings in a List too much for the settings?

Comment: Yeah, sure, but when he runs the application those settings must be loaded from the disk which is where they are stored - so it's exactly the same thing as loading it yourself from a file. It's just that with a BinaryFormatter it will load faster, while the settings use XML.